# SQLite UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: sql, sqlite

Estamos trabajando en un proyecto de bases de datos en el cual tenemos que crear unas tablas en SQLite, sin embargo el código nos está dando un error, pero no tenemos idea de como resolverlo, les agradeceríamos mucho si nos indica como resolverlo.

Comparto el código:

```
CREATE TABLE`FACULTADES`
(`IDFACULTAD` DOUBLE,
`NOMBREFACULTAD` VARCHAR(30),
`EDIFICIO` VARCHAR(3)
)
;
Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('1','Facultad VOY','E92');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('2','Facultad GMA','E51');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('3','Facultad EBK','E16');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('4','Facultad NLV','E10');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('5','Facultad KMV','E46');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('6','Facultad QPL','E93');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('7','Facultad XMF','E46');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('8','Facultad OPD','E20');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('9','Facultad NXL','E79');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('10','Facultad GVX','E25');

Insert into FACULTADES (IDFACULTAD,NOMBREFACULTAD,EDIFICIO) values ('30','Facultad nueva','E78');

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `PK_FACULTADES` ON `FACULTADES` (`IDFACULTAD`);

ALTER TABLE `FACULTADES` ADD CONSTRAINT `PK_FACULTADES` PRIMARY KEY (`IDFACULTAD`);
```

Todo hasta los inserts no está funcionando pero a la hora de llegar al create unique index muestra el siguiente error:

Execution finished with errors.

Result: UNIQUE constraint failed: FACULTADES.IDFACULTAD

At line 29:

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `PK_FACULTADES` ON `FACULTADES` (`IDFACULTAD`);

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con:

```
ALTER TABLE `FACULTADES` ADD UNIQUE(`PK_FACULTADES `);
```

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/349367)

Comment: @RuslanLópez Cierto, creaba un índice en vez de un índice sin suplicados. Ya está corregido

Comment: "Prueba" denota incertidumbre. Si no estás seguro, puedes pedir aclaraciones.

Comment: @CandidMoe Por supuesto. La incertidumbre intrínseca a cada respuesta, de ahí que únicamente pueda ser validada por el autor de la pregunta. A mi entender, dar por hecho que se han entendido todas las aristas de una pregunta, más bien lo que denota es soberbia, y entiendo que aquí estamos para ayudarnos y aportar lo que cada uno pueda dentro de sus posibilidades. Ojalá el OP hubiera continuado la interacción para poder continuar aportando más detalles y mejorando la respuesta. En cualquier caso, tendré en cuenta tu aportación para mejorar el sitio. Saludos.